# vb.net get the index of the current position in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have this `Dim transactionArray As String()()` with full of data and two or more elements have the same value.

When I want to search through the the array to find something, I have:

```
  For Each tempString As String In transactionArray(tempInt1)
     If tempString.Contains(searchText) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Found It")
     End If
  Next
```

Now how would I get the current index? Since I have multiple elemets with the same value, I am guessing that I cannot use `Array.IndexOf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to a for loop:

```
  For I = 0 To transactionArray(tempInt1).Count - 1
     If transactionArray(tempInt1)(I).Contains(searchText) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Found It at index " & I.ToString())
     End If
  Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this according to you

```
Dim strArray As String() = {"ABC", "BCD", "CDE", "DEF", "EFG", "FGH", _
    "GHI"}
Array.IndexOf(strArray, "C")
' not found, returns -1
Array.IndexOf(strArray, "CDE")
' found, returns index
```